# selenium python could not get text of tbody's element

Tags: python, selenium, html-tbody

I have a python code that takes fake mail - sign up a website - then need to enter the code

I use this temp mail service -> [mohmal.com](https://www.mohmal.com/en/inbox)

the inspect HTML is

```
<tbody><tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" style="width:96%;">
<tbody><tr>
<td style="font-size:14px; line-height:16px;">
Mr. Smith,
<br> some text
<br> some text
<br> some text
<br><br><b>614126</b><br> 
<br> some text
<br> some text
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I need the **614126** verification code,

my python code is;

```
theCode = ""
a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > table > tbody > tr > td > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > b")
theCode = a.text
print(theCode )
```

it gives me nothing, I tried

https://www.guru99.com/selenium-webtable.html

these methods, but it didn't work

**EDIT 1:**

the x path the code from insect is like this;

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/b
```

Comment: can you add the website link from which you want to scrape?

Comment: How did you get that css selector string?

Comment: Try following xpath option : `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'Mr. Smith')]//b").text)`

Comment: @Sashaank the website is https://www.mohmal.com/en

Comment: @JohnGordon I used Copy CSS Selector extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-css-selector/kemkenbgbgodoglfkkejbdcpojnodnkg

Comment: @KunduK NoSuchElementException error is given, also can you look my edit on question

Comment: is that user `Mr. Smith` static right?? I mean that value isn't dynamic right.

Comment: its dynnamic @KunduK it depends on what you enter as a name in the website form.

Comment: Well Capture that name in a variable as `variablename` and use it in xpath like this `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'{}')]//b".format(variablename)).text)` Or `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(.,'"+ variablename + "')]//b").text)`